# remove Link Navigation from calendar Date

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the link from the date which gets displayed in sharepoint calendar list.
If I use developer's tool, I do not see any anchor tag on which I can apply CSS to disable. I must achieve this through CSS itself.

The code given below is from sharepoint:

```
<tr class="ms-acal-summary-dayrow"> //Tr which has a class
<td date="5/12/2013" evtid="day">//td i dont know how they fetching this value and entire td has link which has to be removed.
<div>
<nobr>
Text -12 //this text "12"has link
</nobr>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Text-12 has link which I want to remove. How do I achieve this through CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the link by using this as the CSS
`.active {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/7EQJp/